# Conditional MySQL Order By

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with conditional ordering of a mysql query

1. I want to give multiplier first priority for descending order
2. At the second level of priority I want to order by pot in descending
   order **(but only where pot > 80)**
3. At the third level of priority I want to order by points

My problem is how to order by pot but only if pot is > a certain amount.

```
SELECT NAME, POINTS, POT, MULTIPLIER
FROM ITEMS 
ORDER BY MULTIPLIER DESC, 
(CASE WHEN (POT > 80) THEN 'POT DESC,POINTS DESC'
ELSE 'POINTS DESC' END)
```

This is what I tried but, if it meets the condition then it stops ordering by points on the third level of priority...I want it to always order by points on third level priority

example order I would like:

```
multiplier(4),pot(20),points(144)
multiplier(2),pot(90),points(130)
multiplier(2),pot(90),points(13)
multiplier(1),pot(70),points(16783)
multiplier(1),pot(77),points(1653)
multiplier(1),pot(78),points(163)
```

Comment: I don't get the `(but only where pot > 80)` note. How do you want the `pot <= 80` ordered?

Comment: added example of the order id like to get

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
SELECT NAME, POINTS, POT, MULTIPLIER
FROM ITEMS
ORDER BY
  multiplier DESC,
  pot <= 80,
  points DESC
```

Comment: Yes, it becomes a boolean value (1 or 0) and that can be sorted :)

Answer (score 0):

```
ORDER BY multiplier DESC, (CASE WHEN pot > 80 THEN pot ELSE 80 END) DESC, points DESC
```

Comment: how does that work? that would make it "80 DESC"? :)

Comment: The `ORDER BY` clause orders first by `multiplier`, secondly by a calculated value (not the eightieth column!), and thirdly by `points`.